# Gitlab pipeline error - Could not authenticate against gitlab.com

Tags: gitlab

Firstly, apologies if the the information here is very vague but I'm not exactly sure what to add or where to start looking. So I'm happy to add anything else that might help.

At my work we use Gitlab for source control and CI/CD. Everything was fine until a couple of days when a couple of projects suddenly started showing an error when trying to access packages.

The error is happening the when the pipeline running on gitlab is using composer to download the package from the gitlab repo. However I can pull the repos and packages without any issues from my computer.

Now these package repos are also hosted on the same gitlab account. All of this was set up by a previous employee who was way more knowledgeable about dev-ops than I am.

Getting this error

```
Failed to download project/package-name from dist: Could not authenticate against gitlab.com
```

However another package from same repo downloads fine. And since we didn't change anything, I can't understand what is causing this error now.

The project pulling the repos uses a 'gitlab-token' for 'gitlab.com' set in a auth.json file, which hasn't been changed.

I know these issues are difficult to debug over here, but hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you download the project? Do you mean `git clone …`? Was the previous employee also package owner/maintainer and set up the token? If yes has his user  been removed from the project? This could cause his _personal access token_ to be invalidated. As a team in general you should use *group tokens* (see here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html). You could also always use https and use your username/PW combination. Another solution is to generate an SSH key on one machine and use that via SSH.

Comment: I will check if the user's account was removed recently. I am able to access the repo and push it to, because I use SSH keys. Thanks for the tip about the group access tokens, I can set that up. But after I set it up, where would add this token?

Comment: It is stated all in the link. You would use `https` with a blank username and the token as password.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. It lead me to pushing up my auth.json file, which was omitted by gitignore till now - this fixed the pipeline error. But I think there is a security concern to having the auth.json (and the gitlab.com token) visible in the repo, hence it was ignored. Without pushing up the file, can I add this token to somewhere in my repo? Because that's how it must have been getting it so far right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Composer Install Failing All of the Sudden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841798/why-is-composer-install-failing-all-of-the-sudden)

Answer (score 1):

In your pipeline before running `composer install` add this line as-is

```
composer config gitlab-oauth.gitlab.com "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
```

Make sure that:

- you won't replace `${CI_JOB_TOKEN}` with anything - this is gitlab predefined variable
- in the command you'll use `gitlab-oauth` and NOT `gitlab-token`. The latter one works locally but it somehow doesn't work in the gitlab pipeline. I found no documentation why, neither in gitlab nor in composer doc.

The above solved my problem which from your description seems very similar in terms of root cause.