# PHP Composer doesnt work on ec2 linux instance after stp transfer

Tags: php, apache, composer-php

I have a php project that was running on xampp but i created an ec2 instance with linux and i access it with his private ip on putty because the web app is supposed to be accessible just via intranet. i used stp to move the whole project, everything works the same but the composer on some php files give me that error( i got it from apache log)

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/host/public_html/vendor/composer/../ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.composer.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/host/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:41\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/host/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(45): {closure}()\n#1 /var/www/html/host/public_html/vendor/autoload.php(25): ComposerAutoloaderInitc3b80a39a0d2307602d3e5706c8f19a8::getLoader()\n#2 /var/www/html/host/public_html/accessdata.php(18): require('...')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/host/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 41, referer: http://host/page1.php
```

i use composer to use the phpoffice, the user should be able to upload some excel files then using php i upload them on a database

EDIT: when running `composer install`
i get this error
`Failed to download myclabs/php-enum from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/myclabs/php-enum/zipball/a867478eae49c9f59ece437ae7f9506bfaa27483: Connection timeout after 10001 ms`

Comment: Did you check whether the file to be included exists? How is this problem related to Apache?

Comment: How did the `vendor` directory get installed on the server? Did you upload from your local copy or did you run `composer install` on the server?

Comment: @AlexHowansky i uploaded from local copy, i dont have internet access on the server

Comment: "i dont have internet access on the server" - that sounds strange. How did you connect to that server? Also, how do you plan to access that application?

Comment: @NicoHaase i access it with the private ip with putty and the private key, it can be accessed just with intranet, but somehow i cant install composer on linux

Comment: You don't need to install Composer on any production system

Comment: @NicoHaase then how can i fix that error?

Comment: Does the file that should be included exist at the given path?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes i also tried to use chmod so it can have rights to access it

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: You already clarified that there is no normal access to the internet from the server. Hence, downloading files will fail.

Comment: @LajosArpad then how can i make composer to work?

Comment: You could download all resources that would be otherwise downloaded by composer, copy them to the server and install locally.

Comment: @LajosArpad so should i move the vendor folder on the server and then run composer update?

Comment: @LajosArpad i tried moving composer.phar and composer.json on the server then run php composer.phar install but i still receive connection timeout? how can i install locally?

Comment: There should be no need to install Composer on that server in any way. If it is not connected to the public internet, you can't run `composer install` after all

Comment: @NicoHaase but why it doesnt work and i receive HTTP ERROR 500 when using php that contain require vendor/autoload.php, even if the files are there because i copied everything?

Comment: @Mega because even though your files are there it still attempts to download them. I would build a proper structure with composer install using a staging server, compress the project and copy it on the prod server (after thorough testing)

Comment: "HTTP ERROR 500" does not sound like something that Composer throws

Comment: @NicoHaase it's an HTTP error which is thrown upon server error. It seems an error received during the downloading.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841798/x/60844840#60844840)

Comment: `stp transfer`? Never heard of. do you mean `sftp transfer` ? because sftp is a real thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a serious misunderstanding that should be put out of the way right from the beginning:

- If your box has no internet access, you will have little joy with running Composer commands that actually need the internet to fulfill the task you are calling them for.

  - For example the *"composer update"* command you want to run without internet access.
- Composer does no wonders and creates internet access out of no internet access.
- If you not yet see, why this is actually of little surprise, then it must be the serious misunderstanding you have both on Composer and the fundamental difference between Wide Area Network (WAN) and Local Area Network (LAN).
- The best place is localhost btw. Your home is your castle.

So you have certainly a relationship problem in your Composer marriage.

Composer therapist Nico Haase [already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76851282/php-composer-doesnt-work-on-ec2-linux-instance-after-stp-transfer#comment135587314_76851282), *"You don't need to install Composer on any production system"* and if you're looking for a second opinion, I second that. I actually would say, if you're installing Composer on a production system you're asking for trouble, problems, broken hearts (and dependencies).

You [write it your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76851282/php-composer-doesnt-work-on-ec2-linux-instance-after-stp-transfer#comment135585224_76851282):

> i [sic!] uploaded from local copy, i dont [sic!] have internet access on the server

So, **build the vendor folder locally** with Composer, then upload the whole application code (including the vendor directory). Done.

Yes, done.

Machine working again.

And they lived long and happily.

(It may require reading, as every couples therapy is with the work of each individual to find back together. This can be a daunting time, always remind the bright outlook and all the future you two will have together, exploring the wild corners of the intranets together.)

Comment: "Composer therapist" - over the weekend, I'll meditate on this and check whether this should be a compliment :P

Comment: Your endurance in commenting, also on other Q&A in regard of composer is outstanding, truly with the patience a therapist would need to have. Feel free to edit out or let me know what the meditation brought to light.

Comment: @hakre the project is working on my localhost, i copied the whole project but i still get the Failed opening required error, the full error is in the question

Comment: @hakre i think i did some progress but i receive PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\IOFactory" not found in accessdata.php i tried using `use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory` but still not working

Comment: This sounds like it is related to autoloading: While class names in PHP are not case-sensitive, their underlying file-names are (if the file-system is case-sensitive which you **must** assume for portability). Therefore double-check for class/interface/trait/enum not found errors, the correct classname is in use. Check for typos and case sensitivity issues. If you are comparing Windows (local) with Linux (remote), triple check especially case sensitivity issues, as in Windows (and Mac) the file-system traditionally is not case sensitive.

Comment: i used scp to transfer the files and it seems that it missed some vendor files, after using scp more times with specific folders it worked :) you were right with upload the "whole" application, thanks i just needed to check the files

Comment: @Mega: Thanks for the feedback, check the scp return code and also consider rsync as an alternative, it should handle your ssh connection and supports incremental transfers. Often rsync based deployments are the easiest ones to maintain. -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Answer (score 0):

@mega. As you mentioned you have uploaded the `composer.phar` file on server, try creating autoload.php file again by running `composer dump-autoload` command from root folder of your application and check if its working.

`composer dump-autoload` command regenerate the autoload file again and for that you do not need to have internet connection.

If you run into error like "Failed to open stream: Permission denied" try run this command with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

> stp to move the whole project

Never heard of `stp`, maybe you mean `sftp`? given your comment `i access it with the private ip with putty and the private key` , i think `sftp` is a safe bet.

Anyway, something in your vendor folder is messed up, and you can't run composer on the target system, so go to your dev system, and run

```bash
rm -rf vendor;
composer install;
```

after that, idk what  `stp` is, but i don't trust it, i trust `rsync`, so run

```
rsync -aP /path/to/project_dir/vendor user@intranet_ip:/path/to/project_dir/vendor
```

now you should have an intact vendor folder, and the `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/host/public_html/vendor/composer/..`-error should be gone.