# Failed to download symfony/polyfill-php83 from dist: Could not authenticate from against github.com

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm facing an issue while trying to deploy my code from my branch to the staging environment. The pipeline consistently returns the error message 'Failed to download symfony/polyfill-php83 from dist: Could not authenticate from against github.com.' What steps should I take to resolve this? Thank you for your assistance.

I already tried this suggestion [https://statamic.dev/troubleshooting/composer-and-github-authentication#:~:text=If%20you%20receive%20a%20Composer,are%20hitting%20API%20rate%20limits](https://statamic.dev/troubleshooting/composer-and-github-authentication#:%7E:text=If%20you%20receive%20a%20Composer,are%20hitting%20API%20rate%20limits) by still its not working.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841798/why-is-composer-install-failing-all-of-the-sudden